# Firebase - get a list of data from two different nodes

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how the firebase data structure is:

```
    { "Entertainment":{
          "Book":{
                    0:{ id = 1234
                        genre = horror
                        // data of some object type
                      }
                    1:{ id = 2345
                        genre = romance
                      // data of some object type
                      }
                    2:{ id = 3456
                        genre = horror
                      // data of some object type
                      }
                 }
            "Movie":{
                    0:{ id = 6789
                        genre = horror
                        // data of some object type
                      }
                    1:{ id = 9876
                        genre = horror
                      // data of some object type
                      }
                    2:{ id = 0000
                        genre = action
                      // data of some object type
                      }
                 }
           }
  }
```

Now I want to get a list of all books and movies based upon the genre. To retrieve just the books/movies (one type of item) I am doing the following:

```
ItemService.prototype.getItems = function (searchOptions) {
    let _this = this;

    return bookRef
        .orderByKey()
        .once('value')
        .then(function (items) {
            let promises = [];
            let promise;
            let filteredItems = [];
            let item;
            let endTime = '';
            let genre = searchOptions.genre;

            items = items.val();

            for (let key in items) {
                if (items.hasOwnProperty(key) && items[key].genre &&
                    items[key].genre.toLowerCase() === genre.toLowerCase()) {


                    item = items[key];
                    items[key].itemId = key;

                    promise = Promise.resolve(item);
                    promise.then(function (item) {
                            if (!item) {
                                return;
                            }


                            filteredItemss.push({
                                itemId: item.itemId,
                                title: item.item_title,
                                genre: item.genre,
                                ..................
                            });
                        });

                        promises.push(promise);

                }
            }


            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then(function () {

                    filteredItems = _.sortBy(filteredItems, 'title');

                    return {
                        total: filteredItems.length,
                        results: filteredItems
                    };
                })
        });
```

Now, how can I get the list of another item and append the two lists together to return? Basically, what I want to do is, when user selects a genre, then it will show the user a list of all available books and movies under that genre. Can this be achieved? Any help is appreciated, TIA.